# ansible.cfg become_ask_pass not working

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.5.1., and I do not want to use the flag `-K` all the time (I think it will be deprecated soon). I know there is a directive  of `become_ask_pass` in the `ansible.cfg` file.

I set this to be a true value `i.e. become_ask_pass = True`, but running a playbook with this `true` value, gave me an error message and Ansible did not ask for a password.

When I set the deprecated `ask_sudo_pass` t be the true value, then Ansible asked for the password, but printed deprecation information.

I tried to install version 2.6.4 and the behaviour is still the same.

Why `become_ask_pass` and `ask_sudo_pass`, don't work in the same way? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

I consulted the official docs many times before finding a solution.

`ask_sudo_pass` works out of the box when placed inside `ansible.cfg` in your repo, because in a simple configuration file (you have a simple config when you are an apprentice) the only section you probably have is `[defaults]`.

```
[defaults]
some_stuff = ...
ask_sudo_pass = True
```

And this works... because `ask_sudo_pass` should be in the `defaults` section. But `become_ask_pass` should be in the `privilege_escalation` section, not `defaults`:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_ask_pass = True
```

Please pay attention to "Ini section" too, it is as much important as the "Ini value".
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html.